# vb.net - passing string to function and replacing few words in that string

Tags: vb.net

Please help, I need to pass string to function with few optional parameters which needs to be replaced within string. Can someone help how can this be done, as im not to vb.net

```
String - "The <field1> is mandatory"
Variable - Employee Id
Output should be - "The Employee Id is mandatory"
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be looking at the [String.Replace method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx). something like this. Since strings are immutable it returns a new string with your corrected value you would then need to assign it to the old string.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim test As String = "The <field1> is mandatory"
        Dim variable As String = "Employee Id"
        test = test.Replace("<field1>", variable)
        Console.WriteLine(test)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

You could also use the [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9t40k6d.aspx) Method which uses [composite formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) which will allow you to embed fields in your string then replace them with variables. something like this.

```
Dim test As String = "The {0} is a mandatory {1}"
Dim variable As String = "Employee Id"
Dim variable2 As String = "Field"

test = String.Format(test, variable, variable2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
Public Function cal(Byref id)
Dim str as String
str= "The "+id+" is mandatory"
return str
End Function
```

and call this function by

```
s=cal(id) //id is the value to be passed and s is the result
```